# Does Lightroom automatically save the date of printing events, or just the date a print is saved?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, printing

I am trying to discover best way to keep track of printing from Lightroom rather than from printer data.

Answer (score 1):

LR 5.7, at least, notes Print and Export events in each photo's history.

However I use several other practices in my workflow to keep track of what I've printed:

1. I export a copy of everything sent to a printer to a separate folder.
2. I use a color label to indicate that a photo has been printed (and if I want to see exactly what I can either check the photo's history or check the image of the same name in my "Printed" folder.)

If my workflow didn't leave color labels free for this purpose I would use a Keyword Tag like "Printed" for this purpose.